# Best way to trigger BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, timer, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

In my mobile application. I need to trigger a BroadcastReceiver which will show some popup/system notification.

Trigger time of this BroadcastReceiver

1. Every day it should trigger at 13:00.
2. After initial trigger at 13:00. It should trigger every 30 sec.
3. It should stop triggering every 30 sec after 14:00.

I tried the following way

**Using 2 BroadcastReceiver's**

BroacastReceiver 1 is called using AlaramManager

```
    Intent intent = new Intent("broadcast.receiver.one.action");
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,
            intent, 0);
    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, oneAmCalenderObject.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

BroadcastReceiver 1 will start at 13:00 daily and contains a timer which will start BroacastReciever 2 every 30 sec.

```
 timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            if (isLessThanTwoPM()) {
                callBroadcastReceiverTwo();
            } else {
                timer.cancel();
            }

        }
    }, 0, 30 * (1000 * 1));
```

I would like to know, If there is any better way.

Comment: That's pretty insane. So in other words, you want to prevent the device from sleeping for one whole hour and drain a big portion of the battery as a result?

Comment: Well, according to our clients requirement we need to pull data from server every 30sec in that hour. Note: push notifications is not an option.

Comment: for starting the broadcast of every 30 secs. you can setup alarmmanager to boradcast at 1300 and next at 1400 for stopping the broadcast of every 30 secs. Then what u have done is correct but as Xaver Kapeller mentioned it will definitely drain device battery. So would suggest implement a push notification from server when there is an updated data, So upon receiving of push notification you can get data from server and do the needful

Comment: Then your client does not understand how to build an app for a mobile device. What would your client say if the device is just lying around from 13:00 to 14:00 and when you get back to it at 15:00 the battery is almost completely drained? You are the developer, you are the expert. The client will (almost) never have the same technical expertise, and as such your are responsible for making technical decisions. The client can't just dictate how you implement stuff because you are supposed to know better.

Comment: @RajenRaiyarela, I clearly understand that it will drain user's battery. I tried implementing push notifications. But, The delivery mechanism of push notification is not reliable. Since I need to receive data every 30sec(We need to send rapid push notifications i.e., 1 push notification per user every 30sec). The push notifications are not delivering at all times.

Comment: @XaverKapeller please read the above comment. And can you suggest any other possible ways.

Comment: @user3616287 Push notifications are not supposed to be used to transfer real data in the first place. They are just supposed to notify you of something, for example that there is some new data which you can download. And you would do that then independently of the push notifications.

Comment: If the push notifications are not getting delivered. I need to maintain a Service/Looper in my application. Which need to pull data from server. I am so confused.

Comment: @XaverKapeller my data is similar to chat messages. I will get new data every 30sec.

Comment: @user3616287 well then why do you need to download data that often in the first place? That is the main issue here. What purpose could that have? And nobody can suggest a better solution if you don't give us all the information, "i need to download data every 30 seconds for one hour" is not enough. The information we need is why you need to download data. Why every 30 seconds? What kind of data is it and what do you do with it?

Comment: And why are you not using the geofencing api for that?

Comment: Here: https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html

Comment: @XaverKapeller As you mentioned I can check if the device is inside that region at server side and send push notification once it is inside. But, it is making a huge load on server. Say I have this application in 10 devices where each device has 10 regions that's needs to be checked. That means I need to check 100 regions, if it is inside that region.

Comment: @XaverKapeller well geofencing api will help only if the device is user's mobile. But my GPS device is not user's mobile. I have another device fixed to Vehicle.

Comment: You don't need to handle even one bit of that yourself. You don't even need a server for that. I guess you really never heard of the geofencing api... It does exactly what you want. You specify an area and then you get enter and exit events. The rest is already taken care of for you.

Comment: In that case i would suggest connecting phone to vehicle GPS device and using the mock location from setting you can use this. You need to do bit of R&D on this how to connect to vehicle GPS device

Comment: @user3616287 just to confirm i correctly understand is application flow like this - vehicle GPS device send co-ordinates to server, phone gets that co-ordinates from server and in phone it displays a notifcation by checking the area?

Comment: @user3616287 but you are asking a question about the android app. If the other device is not running Android then this question does not apply to that. For Android devices you can simply use geofencing, it's simple, it works, it does not drain a ton of battery. It's the perfect solution for this.

Comment: @XaverKapeller My GPS device is non android

Comment: @user3616287 Then the android device just has to get the GPS data from the server?

Comment: @XaverKapeller Thats what I am doing. And facing problem while getting that data.

Comment: And the whole point of this is that you want to react to the vehicle entering or leaving a certain area?

Comment: @XaverKapeller Exactly

Comment: Perform all the work on the server. Use push notifications to notify devices when the vehicle enters or leaves an area. Also call a webservice on the server each time the app is started which checks where the vehicle is or if there is something which the user needs to be notified of. You can also poll the server every 10 minutes as long the app is open, but I discourage that, do it only if you really have to and never in shorter intervals than 10 minutes. 10 minutes is more than enough. This strategy will work reliably 99,5% of the time and is a million times better then what you had planned.

Answer (score 0):

Use AlarmManager where you can schedule time when to trigger broadcast and till when it has to trigger and then you can stop it also

check out this links

[First Link](http://karanbalkar.com/2013/07/tutorial-41-using-alarmmanager-and-broadcastreceiver-in-android/)

[Second Link](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2015/04/example-of-using-alarmmanager-to.html)

Comment: There so many examples you can search on google. AlarmManager is best way to trigger broadcast receiver. you dont need any service or background process to run for triggering broadcast receiver

Comment: I have given answer on the basis of question u have asked at first and alarm manager is good way what more you can use is check this link which is CountDownTimer [Click here] (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html)